# Returning Arrays from .net web service to Java ME web service results in compile error of stub?

Tags: web-services, netbeans, java-me

So, I'm getting some compile errors on netbeans 6.5 generated web service code for a java ME client to a c# (vs2005) web service.  I've trimmed my example significantly, and it still shows the problem, and not being able to return a collection of things is pretty much a deal-breaker.

c# web service (SimpleWebService.asmx)

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="SimpleWebService" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://sphereinabox.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class SimpleWebService  : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [WebMethod]
    public CustomType[] GetSomething() {
        return new CustomType[] {new CustomType("hi"), new CustomType("bye")};
    }
    public class CustomType {
        public string Name;
        public CustomType(string _name) {
            Name = _name;
        }
        public CustomType() {
        }
    }
}
```

WSDL (automatically generated by vs2005):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://sphereinabox.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="http://sphereinabox.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://sphereinabox.com/">
      <s:element name="GetSomething">
        <s:complexType />
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetSomethingResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetSomethingResult" type="tns:ArrayOfCustomType" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfCustomType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="CustomType" nillable="true" type="tns:CustomType" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="CustomType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetSomethingSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSomething" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetSomethingSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSomethingResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="SimpleWebServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSomething">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetSomethingSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetSomethingSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="SimpleWebServiceSoap" type="tns:SimpleWebServiceSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSomething">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://sphereinabox.com/GetSomething" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="SimpleWebServiceSoap12" type="tns:SimpleWebServiceSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSomething">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://sphereinabox.com/GetSomething" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="SimpleWebService">
    <wsdl:port name="SimpleWebServiceSoap" binding="tns:SimpleWebServiceSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost/SimpleWebService/SimpleWebService.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="SimpleWebServiceSoap12" binding="tns:SimpleWebServiceSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost/SimpleWebService/SimpleWebService.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Generated (netbeans) code that fails to compile, this was created going through the "Add -> New JavaME to Web Services Client" wizard.  (SimpleWebService_Stub.java)

```
    public ArrayOfCustomType GetSomething() throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        Object inputObject[] = new Object[] {
        };

        Operation op = Operation.newInstance( _qname_operation_GetSomething, _type_GetSomething, _type_GetSomethingResponse );
        _prepOperation( op );
        op.setProperty( Operation.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, "http://sphereinabox.com/GetSomething" );
        Object resultObj;
        try {
            resultObj = op.invoke( inputObject );
        } catch( JAXRPCException e ) {
            Throwable cause = e.getLinkedCause();
            if( cause instanceof java.rmi.RemoteException ) {
                throw (java.rmi.RemoteException) cause;
            }
            throw e;
        }

//////// Error on next line, symbol ArrayOfCustomType_fromObject not defined
        return ArrayOfCustomType_fromObject((Object[])((Object[]) resultObj)[0]);
    }
```

it turns out with this contrived example (the "CustomType" in my production problem has more than one field) I also get errors from this fun code in the same generated (SimpleWebService_Stub.java) generated code.  The errors are that string isn't defined (it's String in java, and besides I think this should be talking about CustomType anyway).

```
private static string string_fromObject( Object obj[] ) {
    if(obj == null) return null;
    string result = new string();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Clearly* you shouldn't be using fancy built-in things like netbeans's stub generator.  Noes, you should be using the Sun (or Sprint branded...) stub generator which you can get to by:

1. Right-Clicking your project
2. select **Properties**
3. Select **Platform** on the left side of new dialog
4. Click on **Manage Emulators** on the rigt side
5. Select the emulator of your choice (**Sun Java(TM) Wirless Tookit 2.5 for CLDC**) on the left of this new dialog
6. Click on the **Tools & Extensions** tab.
7. Click the **Open Utilities** button.
8. Select the **Stub Generator** Utility in this new dialog
9. Cry about the large number of steps and dialogs involved.
10. Click **Launch**
11. Specify your WSDL Url **http://localhost/SimpleWebService/SimpleWebService.asmx?WSDL**
12. Specify your ouput path ** C:\code\SimpleMobile\src\ **
13. Specify your output package **simplewebservice** or whatever you
14. Press the **OK** button.
15. Ignore the errors about being unable to compile if you're going to compile with netbeans. **error : com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not availble in the classpath..
    error: comilation failed, errors should have been reported**
16. Repeat all of the above any time the web service changes, and the stubs need to be regenerated.
17. Write a batch file to do this to save your sanity.

ugh. Well anyway, the above I found in Jonathan Knudsen's book "Kicking Butt with MIDP and MSA: Creating Great Mobile Applications"

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is great, I had classcastexception when I used the netbeans generated stub class, java me platform SDK 3 generated class works like a charm.

Java ME platform SDK 3 and netbeans 6.8 does not show the open utilities button (can't click on it), but you can open Java ME platform SDK 3 to generate the stub class

create a new project,
right click on project name:
add - other
choose other, mobile web service client, specify WSDL URL
and woila, you have the working generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

in web service add attribute [Serializable] for class CustomType.
the you will get ArrayOfCustomType_fromObject() in stub class.